# PHP return AJAX call but code statement not able to recognize

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am totally lost, I used the AJAX below to post data to PHP and echo "1". However, the code couldnt get into the "if (result==1)" code block. It always go into the ELSE block I have attempted to alert(result). It shows 1 without any problem. Apologize for my bad explanation. Any help is deeply appreciated.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                // ... Process the result ...
                //alert(result);

                if (result=="1")
                {
                swal({
                  type: "success",  
                  title: "Congratulation!",
                  text: "Please check your email inbox",
                  animation: "slide-from-top",
                  showConfirmButton: true
                  }, function(){   

                    var username = $("#username").val();
                    var password = $("#password").val();


                });



                }

                else
                {
                //alert(result);
                swal({
                  type: "error",
                  title: "",
                  text: result,
                  animation: "slide-from-top",
                  showConfirmButton: true
                });     



                }




            }

        });
```

My PHP Code is as below:

```
if($dum=="TRUE")
{    

    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    $country = $_POST['id_country'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $agent = $_POST['agent'];
    $term = $_POST['term'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO usercabinet (username, password, password2, fullname, country, mobile, email, agent, term, emailconfirm, identityconfirm, feeds)
VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$password2', '$fullname', '$country', '$mobile', '$email', '$agent', '$term', '0', '0', 'Welcome to Our New Cabinet')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    // "New record created successfully, Success!!<br>";

    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['fullname'] = $fullname;
    $_SESSION['country'] = $country;
    $_SESSION['mobile'] = $mobile;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $country;
    $_SESSION['term'] = $term;
    $_SESSION['emailconfirm'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['identityconfirm'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['feeds'] = "Welcome to Cabinet";


    echo "1";

}
```

What could be the possible reason of fail?

Comment: `console.log(result);` and see what you get

Comment: @mega6382. Thanks for your reply.. Could you please guide me how to check trailing space?? I attempted with modifying echo"1" to $result =1; echo $result; but it stil fails.. I am new to this..

Comment: Please check the data type of "result" by following

alert(typeof result);

Comment: If the provided solution was helpful. Please be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
result = trim(result);
if(result == 1){
```

This will remove any trailing spaces from the string. Or you can make sure there is no space after or before `<?php ?>` tags. OR better yet, you can submit `json` response from PHP Like:

```
$result = ['status' => 'success'];
echo json_encode($result);
```

And in your js something like:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    type: 'POST',
    data: $form.serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result)
    {
        if (result.status=="success")
    }
});
```